# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - How to install MobileFirst Runtime with Ant scripts

Tags: ant, installation, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

How to install MobileFirst runtime with ant scripts, in most of the documentation it suggest to use Installation Manager but we want to use ant scripts to do this installation. And where can I find this ant scripts.

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific Ant scripts/tasks for installation of the MobileFirst binaries itself, but it ought to relatively easily be able to get your Ant script to call the MobileFirst [silent install](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_silent_installation.html) using an [`<exec>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) or similar.

Note that the next step is then typically to install the MobileFirst administration .war, that *is* (or can be) managed [using an Ant task](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/r_wlconsole_ant_tasks.html).

Comment: The silent Installation [URL](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_silent_installation_working_with_sample_response_files.html) you provide have sample zip file which have sample Ant Scripts but it only contains scripts for 6.0 and 7.0 where can I get scripts for 7.1?